# Magento 2 : How I can change the default font Icon in menu admin for custom module?

Tags: magento2, adminmenu

I need to add font icon in the admin menu.

Like all the core magento 2 menus, by default it shows the hexagonal icon for custom module menu, how can I change it?

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**1. Create Icon**

By default, Magento 2 add a custom default icon for your module.

But you can add your custom icon to your custom admin module menu.

Create custom icon .svg with Inkscape software (open source soft for

creating vector try man !).

Create font icon of that .svg icon with help of IcoMoon.io

Go to  `lib/web/fonts`

create your module folder. example `Package` and paste all files obtained/exported from IcoMoon.io.

2. **injected it inside Magento 2 without touching the core files:**
   Supposed your module name is `Package_Modulename`

go to app/design/adminhtml/Magento/backend

create folder with name  Package_Modulename/web/css/source/

Create `_module.less` file under the source folder

It will seem like `Package_Modulename/web/css/source/_module.less`

Now inside your file _module.less add this lines :

```
@modulename-icons-admin__font-name-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/modulename/icomoon';
@modulename-icons-admin__font-name : 'modulename';
.font-face(
@family-name:@modulename-icons-admin__font-name,
@font-path: @modulename-icons-admin__font-name-path,
@font-weight: normal,
@font-style: normal
);
.admin__menu .item-modulename.parent.level-0 > a:before {
  font-family: @modulename-icons-admin__font-name;
  content: "\e800";
}
```

item-modulename : here `modulename` is comes from `etc/adminhtml/menu.xml`

```
<menu>
        <add id="Package_Modulename::modulename" title="Modulename" module="Package_Modulename" sortOrder="40" resource="Package_Modulename::modulename"/> 
</menu>
```

see the id Magento take the last word after ':: ' here is  `modulename` and add the name to `li` html parent of `a` tag the class result is `class='item-modulename  parent  level-0'`

For more step by step understanding, you can refer to http://ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-backend-how-to-create-custom-menu-in-admin-and-change-default-font-icon

Comment: BTW it should be .lib-font-face or .font-face?

Comment: I m not sure how this worked for you? which gives .font-face is undefined error. Use .lib-font-face instead.

Comment: I had used it into beta version. I am doing it now into stable and let you know.

Comment: it is not works for me.

Comment: Can you please advice in detail, what thing do you face there?

Comment: Which version of M2 are you using? I need to check it into Magento 2.0.5 and later and it might be need to update accordingly.

Comment: I have done same as this post, but doesn't work for me. Can you please check with 2.0.6 and update it if necessary.

Comment: Sure. I will do it in 2.0.7 & 2.1.0 and will update here

Comment: Read this post, we describe in steps how to change in an easy way: http://www.uecommerce.com.br/change-default-icon-for-top-level-menu-backend-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 6):

I tried the above solution but it did not work for me. so I tried to put `_module.less` file in

```
vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/Your_Module/web/css/source
```

Directory. and it works for me.

This is not recommended but I didn't find any other solution for this. so I try this solution. and it works.
check the following file to make sure it works:

```
 pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.less
```

Where you should find a line like this:

```
@import '../Your_Module/css/source/_module.less';
```

Comment: Read this post, we describe in steps how to change in an easy way:
http://www.uecommerce.com.br/change-default-icon-for-top-level-menu-backend-in-magento-2/

Thanks

Comment: The vendor folder is subject to a lot of change, as soon as you do a Magento security patch, this change will vanish if using this route. And if you use a deploy system, this change will never appear.

Answer (score 5):

Above mentioned answers are worked the different folders like `lib`, `design`.

So we have only worked on the custom extension files. The step is:

1. you have create the `menu.xml` file for `Package_Modulename/etc/adminhtml`. Code is
2. Create font icon of that .svg icon with help of [IcoMoon.io](https://icomoon.io/app/#/select). More details [Documents](https://icomoon.io/#docs/stroke-to-fill)
3. Create the `default.xml` file for `Package_Modulename/view/adminhtml/layout`. Coding are:
4. Create the `fonts` folder in `Package_Modulename/view/adminhtml/web` and paste the icon files. Files are

> icon.eot
>
> icon.svg
>
> icon.ttf
>
> icon.woff

5. Create the `icon.css` file for `Package_Modulename/view/adminhtml/web/css`. Code are

   @font-face {
   font-family:'Packagename';
   src:url('../fonts/icon.eot');
   src:url('../fonts/icon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),url('../fonts/icon.woff') format('woff'),url('../fonts/icon.ttf') format('truetype'),url('../fonts/icon.svg') format('svg');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal
   }

   .admin__menu .level-0.item-package_menu > a::before {
   content: '\e900';
   font-size: 3.0rem;
   padding-top: 0.1rem;
   font-family:'Packagename';
   }

> Note: Above coding `content: '\e900';` check the value. Please check
> font package file (`demo.html`). Refer the screen shot:

[image]

Comment: It worked me and it's very solution when have a sass implementation in frontend and not like compile less in admin area.

Comment: @jruzafa, Above comment does not understand. Please comment once again with detailed.

Answer (score 0):

Another "hackish" way to do it is to add a transparent png image in the `vendor/modulename/view/adminhtml/web/images/icon.png` and a few css lines in the `vendor/modulename/view/adminhtml/web/css/styles.css`:

```
/* you may have to adjust the selector a bit*/
.admin__menu .item-{modulename}-menu.last.level-0 > a:before {
    background: url("../images/icon.png") center center no-repeat;
    content: "";
    background-size: auto 95%;
}

.admin__data-grid-wrap .data-grid .data-grid-draggable .data-row .data-grid-thumbnail-cell .admin__control-thumbnail > img:before {
    border:none;
}
```

I personally had difficulties generating the webfonts and to be honest I find that approach a bit too much for an admin icon (1kb image).

Answer (score 0):

You could also look for an admin icon that already exists and matches your needs inside the [*Iconography in Magento Admin Pattern Library*](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/pattern-library/graphics/iconography/iconography.html) and then look for the corresponding LESS variable at `vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/css/source/variables/_icons.less` file.

If you find something useful in this library, create your LESS file directly inside your module (no need for an adminhtml theme) at `Vendor/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/css/source/_module.less` and fill it with following content:

```
.admin__menu .item-modulename.parent.level-0 > a:before {
  content: @icon-tool__content; // Or whatever icon variable you want
}
```

Then, you must remove `pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.css` file, and reload the admin page

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Create the CSS file first in view/adminhtml/web/css/ in your extension:
File path : app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/css/adminhtml.css

```
.admin__menu .level-0.item-menuid > a:before {
    content: url('../images/icon-devline.png'); //content: "\0041";
}
```

### menu id from menu.xml file

Step 2: Create default.xml file
File path : app\code\Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\layout\default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module::css/adminhtml.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

step 3:
run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area adminhtml
```