# How Does Magento Include the admin-icons.svg File?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, magento-2.0, fonts

In Magento 2, the icons for the backend Menu are Unicode code points that are part of the [Private User Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) code point range, and appear to be defined via the file

```
vendor/magento//theme-adminhtml-backend/web/fonts/admin-icons/admin-icons.svg
```

How does `admin-icons.svg` get included into a Magento Admin Page's "font space" (for lack of a better word).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So if I got it right:

- The path of this file is defined in a less variable in `app/design/adminhtml/Magento/backend/web/css/source/variables/_icons.less`:

  ```
  @icons-admin__font-name-path: '@{baseDir}fonts/@{icons-admin__file-name}/@{icons-admin__file-name}';
  ```
- This variable is then used in `app/design/adminhtml/Magento/backend/web/css/source/_icons.less` (see the difference with the first file I mentionned ? it's one folder above) to be declared as a path to a custom font :

  ```
  .lib-font-face(
      @family-name: @icons-admin__font-name,
      @font-path: @icons-admin__font-name-path,
      @font-weight: normal,
      @font-style: normal
  );
  ```

Even though the final rendered CSS looks like this:

```
src: url('../fonts/admin-icons/admin-icons.eot');
```

I don't think Magento converts the SVG file to an EOT file.

To me, Magento is shipped with 5 different versions of the same file:

- admin-icons.eot
- admin-icons.svg
- admin-icons.ttf
- admin-icons.woff
- admin-icons.woff2

All those 5 files are then referenced in the `lib/web/css/source/lib/_typography.less` file:

```
.lib-font-face(
    @family-name,
    @font-path,
    @font-weight: normal,
    @font-style: normal
) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: @family-name;
        src: url('@{font-path}.eot');
        src: url('@{font-path}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('@{font-path}.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('@{font-path}.woff') format('woff'),
        url('@{font-path}.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('@{font-path}.svg#@{family-name}') format('svg');
        font-weight: @font-weight;
        font-style: @font-style;
    }
}
```

I reckon it has to do with browser compatibilities. Again I may be wrong here.

Comment: Hopefully the last question!  Any idea how Magento converts the SVG file into an eot file? (the final rendered CSS looks like this `src: url('../fonts/admin-icons/admin-icons.eot');`)

Comment: @AlanStorm see my update ;) not 100% sure on this one

Comment: Nice work Raphael -- lets see what the rest of the community can come up w/r/t to those font files. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114576/how-does-magento-2-generate-the-admin-icons-font-files

Comment: @AlanStorm hopefully I missed something and Magento provided us a nice tool to generate those files

Comment: In module context, this worked for me: http://www.uecommerce.com.br/change-default-icon-for-top-level-menu-backend-in-magento-2/