# How Does Magento 2 Generate the admin-icons Font Files?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, backend, fonts

In Magento 2, the icons for backend Menu Items are [Private User Area code points](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/114570/how-does-magento-include-the-admin-icons-svg-file/114572) added via a custom font file.

The `_typography.less` file appears to ship with the ability to conditionally include one of five font files (`.eot`, `.svg`, `.ttf`, `.woff`, `.woff2`).  The font file that defines these custom endpoint is named `admin-icons`.

What not clear is if Magento (via LESS CSS, or some other means) ships with the ability to **generate** these five font files, or if an extension developer is expected to create all five themselves?  i.e. it's easy enough to use an Icon Generation program like `IcoMoon` to create a `svg` version of the font, but does a Magento 2 module developer also need to create `eot`, `ttf`, `woff`, or `woff2` files themselves?

If not -- **how can you use Magento to generate these files from the `svg`.**

If so -- **what tools do people use to create the `eot`, `ttf`, `woff`, or `woff2` versions of the font?**

Comment: As a side note the IcoMoon app contain all necessary webfont formats (WOFF, TTF, EOT, SVG) so it's possible that Magento directly used the IcoMoon app for all of those files

Comment: True. IcoMoon is used by internal Magento frontend developers to generate all custom fonts. And yes, better to generate all possible formats (eot, ttf, etc) since I believe you'd like to have all browsers working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I assumed and as Vitalii confirmed in the comments, **the [IcoMoon App](https://icomoon.io/) is used internally by Magento frontend developers to generate the custom fonts file.**

The app lets you generate every possible format:

- WOFF
- TTF
- EOT
- SVG

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be superfluous for them to include every app and tool they've used to develop the software (and the graphics involved).

What's confusing about it is that they put you in a habit of expecting everything because you can access their UI elements, although that is web development.

I'm sure they wouldn't include an app like this for the sake of generating additional files for the icons. And I believe the designers for the UI aren't as savvy as programmers when it comes to generating things like that. For them it's a one time job once their design is approved.