# Add image to new backend top menu

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, menu, topmenu, adminmenu

i've successfully create a top menu in magento 2 like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Test::top_level" module="Namespace_Module" resource="Magento_Backend::content" sortOrder="40" title="Test"/> 
    </menu>
</config>
```

the default menu image is octagon, how can i add my own image as my new top menu image

[image]

Comment: please check https://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-change-default-icon-in-menu-for-custom-module/

Comment: Please check here..  https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/91826/49315